TensorFlow 2.16.2 does not detecting my GPU
I got RTX 4060 with driver 560.76.
I installed CUDA 11.8 and copied cuDNN 8.9.7. files to the correct directories in the CUDA installation folder.
I added the right paths to the System variables Environment.
Finally, I installed Tensorflow 2.16.2.
When I run the code below I got no GPU detection:
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices(‘GPU’)))

What am I doing wrong?

Actually, from TensorFlow 2.11 and newer versions do not have anymore native support for GPUs on Windows, so everything was okay from your side. See from the TensorFlow website:

Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that
supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you
will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu
and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin.

From TensorFlow 2.11 onwards, to get GPU support on Windows, you need to use WSL2 or if you don't want to use WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux), use older version of TensorFlow that supports native GPU on Windows.

And how do you know this is a Windows native installation? What if it is Linux or WSL?

This generally happens when TensorFlow 2.11 is installed in Windows Native Installation, and everything is installed in correct location. Otherwise, there is nothing to cause the issue. [Exception: If the GPU is not connected or configured properly.]

Thanks, I used TensorFlow 2.10 in the end and it worked.
